# Unexpected __-prefixed public variables in XSDObjectGen.exe auto generated code

Tags: c#, xsd, code-generation, xsd.exe

I have auto generated some classes from an xsd file using the [XSDObjectGen.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=89E6B1E5-F66C-4A4D-933B-46222BB01EB0&displaylang=en) tool. My classes contain extra public variables, named using leading underscores, and I cannot figure out why.

Here's a sample from the xsd file:

```
<xs:attribute name="Fare" type="xs:int" use="required">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>The fare price in pence</xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
</xs:attribute>
```

The corresponding auto generated C# code is:

```
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Fare", DataType = "int")]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
public int __Fare;

[XmlIgnore]
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
public bool __FareSpecified;

[XmlIgnore]
public int Fare
{
    get { return __Fare; }
    set { __Fare = value; __FareSpecified = true; }
}
```

I understand all of this code, including the attributes. However, I do not understand *why* it has been implemented this way.

- Why does this class serialize the `__Fare` rather than the `Fare` property? In this case the `__Fare` variable would be private (and renamed `_fare`) or an auto-property could be used.
- What is the purpose of the `__FareSpecified` variable?

Our feeling is that the `__`-prefixed variables are just going to add inconvenience for any developers who consume these classes, so plan to rewrite as follows:

```
[XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "Fare", DataType = "int")]
public int Fare{ get; set;}
```

Or even just:

```
[XmlAttribute]
public int Fare{ get; set;}
```

Can anyone shed any light on the rationale behind the `__`-prefixed variables?

Note that our xsd file is not expected to change often, if ever, so our ability to re-auto generate these classes is not important.

### Edit

I double-checked with the team here, this source code was actually generated using XSDObjectGen.exe, not xsd.exe as I originally said.

Comment: I haven't used XOG yet.  I'm not exactly happy that it pulls this nonsense as well.  The newer XML tools created for WCF and related technologies (such as serializers) work better than the old 2.0 stuff,  IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Its to differentiate between the public property and its backing variable.

XSD does the XXXSpecified nonsense for non-nullable types.

I'm not a particular fan of the XSD tool because of stuff like this.  Take a look at the [XSDObjectGen](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=89e6b1e5-f66c-4a4d-933b-46222bb01eb0&displaylang=en) or [WSDL.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(VS.80).aspx) and see if they work better for you.